# Can I send a variable to my PHP code when I use $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I currently have some JQuery code where I send the variable 'name' to a PHP file, and that PHP file calls the data in row 'name'

```
//JQuery Code
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('#question > h1').load('/php/getQuestion.php', { 
        name: qty
    });
});

//PHP Code Below
$value = (integer)$_POST["name"];
$sql = "SELECT `question_id`, `question` FROM Question WHERE `question_id` = 
{$value}";
```

I want to do a similar call using JQuery's $.getJSON. Currently this is my code:

```
var requestAnswer = ($.getJSON('[URL HERE]'));
```

Is there any way I could send the value of 'name' to my PHP code and get only the JSON request from row: 'name'. Something like:

```
var requestAnswer = ($.getJSON('[URL HERE]'),{ name:2});
```

I know this example doesn't work.

Comment: Just use `$_REQUEST['name']` instead of `$_POST['name']`. As $.getJSON() send data with default GET method and not by POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the query string into the url like that

```
$.getJSON('getQuestion.php?name=abc', function(data) {
//process data here
});
```

on Server side, use `$_GET["name"]` to retrieve parameter

Comment: @AlivetoDie: I didn't read the document but It works so It's not the wrong way. Btw, it's more standard to use $.getJSON('getQuestion.php',{name:2}, function(data) {
//process data here
});

Comment: @huydq5000  i will suggest you to read documentation then, because this is the default behaviour of `$.getJSON` that second parameter (plain-object) will converted to query-string, so use the standered way not hard-code the value yourself. this is like don't follow the standered. BTW i have no issue with you man. chill

Comment: @AlivetoDie: I already agreed that your answer is more standard than mine in previous post :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on  [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) documentation:-

You can pass your data as the second parameter:

```
$.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )
```

***like below:-***

```
$.getJSON( "Url", {name:2},function( data ) {
      //code based on data
});
```

***Again the documentation says:-***

*"Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string. If the value of the data parameter is a plain object, it is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL."*

So you can retrieve it to php end by using:-

```
$_GET['name'];
```